# In R, what do I need to do when my Radio API is on commercial break

Tags: r, json, api, web-scraping

Right now, I am trying to get my function to run every so often to check if there's a new song and add it to a data frame. This is so I can figure out what are the most played songs. My code runs great until the API gives a commercial break, I read the json by doing this

```
jsonlite::read_json(
    "https://us.api.iheart.com/api/v3/live-meta/stream/2501/currentTrackMeta?defaultMetadata=true")
```

And when it goes to commercial break I get this error

```
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(con, "rb") :
  cannot open URL 'https://us.api.iheart.com/api/v3/live-meta/stream/2501/currentTrackMeta?defaultMetadata=true': HTTP status was '204 No Content'
```

Does anyone know how I can still run my code every minute or so even through commercial breaks?

Comment: Use [`try`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/try.html) or [`tryCatch`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/conditions.html), and if you get an error, wait a moment and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have `options(warn=2)` or higher, since for me that is a `Warning`, not an error. However, we can resolve that too.

```r
nowplaying <- tryCatch(
  jsonlite::read_json("https://us.api.iheart.com/api/v3/live-meta/stream/2501/currentTrackMeta?defaultMetadata=true"),
  warning = function(w) w,
  error = function(e) e)
if (inherits(nowplaying, c("error", "warning"))) {
  msg <- conditionMessage(nowplaying)
  if (grepl("204 No Content", msg)) {
    message("Stand by for a few words from our sponsors ...")
    # sleep or do something else before re-querying
  } else {
    stop("Oops! Something else is wrong and I should not continue blindly: ",
         msg, call. = FALSE)
    # STOP! if you continue, you might trigger some FW-defense or
    # over-use and get yourself throttled or banned
  }
} else {
  print(nowplaying$album)
  # allegedly sleep a little here before starting all over again
}
```

I put in some extra logic so as to not blindly assume all warnings and errors are transient. If you hit some limit or something else is breaking, this should stop (and you'll be in the "Oops" branch above).

It is *feasible* to use `withCallingHandlers` and `invokeRestart("mufflewarning")` conditioned on the warning/error message, but (1) that's fairly advanced, and (2) since that method allows *continuing* with some processing, that isn't really necessary here, so the add complication is for no real gain.